# How to specify function to collection.find() dynamically

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I pass the function `logic` to the `find`-function in order to use it on each document?

I am trying to find Mongo-documents recursively with certain values in a property. I have defined an "algorithm" and would like to this to the `find`-function, but despite reading about queries, searching and `find()`, I have had no luck.

```
// match every node with propertyname "Reference" with the exact value "43_1"
var logic = function(currentKey, currentValue) {
    return ( currentKey == "Reference" && currentValue === "43_1" );
};

db.getCollection('metavalg').find(function() {  
    function recurSearchObj(doc) {
        return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
            if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" && doc[key] !== null ) {
                return recurSearchObj(doc[key]);
            } else {
                // invoke matching-logic
                return logic(key, doc[key]);
            }
        });
    }
    // search document recursively 
    return recurSearchObj(this);
})
```

---

With the help of Vladimir M, I ended up rearringing the code and doing this:

```
db.getCollection('metavalg').find(function() {  
    function inspectObj(doc, logic) {
        return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
            if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" && doc[key] !== null ) {
                return inspectObj(doc[key], logic);
            } else {
                return logic(key, doc[key]);
            }
        });
    }
    return inspectObj(this, function(currentKey, currentValue) {
        return ( currentKey == "Nummer" && currentValue === "43_1" );
        //return ( currentKey == "Navn" && /max\.? 36/i.test(currentValue) );
    });
})
```

Comment: have it as a property of a data item?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand your question?

Comment: If you want logic to be different for different data items, and you want it to be encapsulated, then essentially you want each data item in the collection to be an object with same interface find(), which encapsulates logic that is particular to the item. Then inside the find iterator over the collection you just have to call find() on each item w/o knowing anything about their internal data.

Comment: I have refined my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass logic method as a parameter to recurcive search object:

```
// match every node with propertyname "Reference" with the exact value "43_1"
var logic = function(currentKey, currentValue) {
    return ( currentKey == "Reference" && currentValue === "43_1" );
};

db.getCollection('metavalg').find(function() {  
    function recurSearchObj(doc, aLogic) {
        return Object.keys(doc).some(function(key) {
            if ( typeof(doc[key]) == "object" && doc[key] !== null ) {
                return recurSearchObj(doc[key], aLogic);
            } else {
                // invoke matching-logic
                if( aLogic(key, doc[key]) ){
                       // then do somthing 
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // search document recursively 
    return recurSearchObj(this, logic);
});
```